# Identify which set this bag of trunk and leaf pieces belongs to

Tags: set-identification

[image]

Please help me identify which set this belongs to! Looks like pieces to a tree maybe? Inside the big bag there is a mini bag with some flame pieces and more green and brown pieces. The front of the bag says "2", 2011, and "135149".

Comment: There is no picture to help us figure out what set this is and make sure it is the right set, and very small amount of detail on the set, therefore voting to close this question

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE, Jill! If you are able to edit your post to add a photo of this bag and its contents, someone here can probably figure this out for you. Without a photo, it will be difficult, if not impossible, to answer.

Comment: Ok thank you that is a tree it goes to a fire truck set that i forgot the number of

Answer (score 5):

This is bag # 2 of Set # [4209-1: Fire Plane](https://brickset.com/sets/4209-1/Fire-Plane)

[image]

Based on the Trans-Orange [Wave Rounded with Base Rim (Castle Dragon Flame, Seaweed, Water)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6126b&idColor=98#T=C&C=98)

and the Green [Wedge, Plate 3 x 6 Cut Corners](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2419&idColor=6#T=C&C=6)